# How do I append an item to my ListModel that's been defined not in the main.qml file

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Let's say I have a ListModel component in A.qml:

```
ListModel {
    id: alphabetModel
}
```

I have a seperate JS file to append items into my ListModel:

```
alphabetModel.append({"Letter": "A"});
```

If I run my code, I get a reference error:

```
ReferenceError: alphabetModelis not defined
```

I know I wouldn't get the ReferenceError if my ListModel was in main.qml and I did import my JS file into my A.qml.

Any way of resolving this reference error?

Comment: Can you please show more code, where you are trying to use it? You will need to give your JS a reference to the `ListModel` somehow, since the id might be unique in the file only. Maybe it would be also better for you to use a C++ (or Python?)-defined QAbstractListModel-descendent.

Comment: read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Pass `id` of your` ListModel` to your js function. Otherwise you have to make pointer to `ListModel` visible in other files. May be by storing the `id` with some global object or whatever ...

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Including a JavaScript Resource from Another JavaScript Resource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html)

This following example is taken from the link above :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "script.js" as MyScript

Item {
 width: 100; height: 100

MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        MyScript.showCalculations(10)
        console.log("Call factorial() from QML:",
            MyScript.factorial(10))
    }
}
}
```

script.js

```
// script.js
Qt.include("factorial.js")
function showCalculations(value) {
  console.log("Call factorial() from script.js:"),factorial(value));
}
```

factorial.js

```
// factorial.js
function factorial(a) {
 a = parseInt(a);
 if (a <= 0)
    return 1;
 else
    return a * factorial(a - 1);
}
```