# QT QML Accessing Attached Property From Another QML Object

Tags: qt, qml, attached-properties

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    x: 200
    y: 200
    visible: true

    Component {
        id: firstViewComponent
        FirstView {
            id: firstView
        }
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        Component.onCompleted: push(firstViewComponent)
    }

    Timer {
          interval: 1000
          running: true
          onTriggered: stackView.pop()
    }
}
```

FirstView.qml:

```
Rectangle {
    id: view
    StackView.onDeactivating: console.log('view: view is deactivating')

    ListModel {
        id: aModel
        ListElement {
            name: 'Element 0'
        }
        ListElement {
            name: 'Element 1'
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        model: aModel

        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: listViewDelegate
            Connections {
                target: view.StackView  // <---- DOESN'T WORK
                onDeactivating: console.log('delegate ' + index + ': needs to do some housekeeping now')
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

I have a view that is instantiated by a StackView in main.qml. The StackView attaches a signal StackView.onDeactivating to the view. Is there any way to attach to the signal from an object other than the one the signal is attached to? I need to do some cleanup in listViewDelegate when the view is popped.

I could have view emit its own signal, and have the delegate respond to that signal. But what I'm wondering is if there is a way to connect to the attached signal: StackView.onDeactivating from a different object (listViewDelegate).

Comment: what is `myView`?, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596536/how-do-i-append-an-item-to-my-listmodel-thats-been-defined-not-in-the-main-qml/52607595#52607595)

Comment: @eylianesc correcting.

Comment: still correcting..@Redanium I have a basic understanding of qml and js, this pertains to accessing an Attached Property, which is a qml concept.

Comment: @eylianesc corrected.

Comment: @Colin I think that you have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), you are asking for a possible solution that you do not have certainty that works instead of your real problem. What is your real problem?

Comment: @eyllanesc properties of a qml object are public - they are accessible by other objects. The question I am trying to ask is: are attached properties effectively private. As far as I can tell the answer is yes. But I am looking for a more expert opinion.

Comment: @Colin That it is public does not imply that they are global, the objects have a certain scope, the misunderstanding of it causes problems like the one you have (although until now I do not know what you are trying to do), by design a component must be independent of the exterior, that is to say not depend explicitly from outside and therefore QML offers the properties and signals that allows decoupling, for me you are thinking with a different paradigm, QML is declarative.

Comment: @Colin in QML there is no explicit concept of private and public. In QML the concept of scope is used instead as in most declarative languages

Comment: @eyllanesc so, it looks to me like it is not possible to access an attached property outside the scope of the object it is attached to. Maybe that is my answer. I have read discussions of qml where the concept of private is used for the purpose of understanding qml (for example here: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qml-coding-conventions.html#private-properties). If anyone would like to chime in on this question, though, please feel free.

Comment: @Colin I think your question has no answer because you are asking for non-existent things, as the link does not exist the concept of private in QML, but the concept of hidden that is different from private, you are thinking of OOP, QML is declarative is not OOP.

Comment: @Colin finally use the modern documentation, your link is Qt4, and if we look at the current docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-codingconventions.html that paragraph has already been deleted.

Comment: In terms of the coding question I am trying to solve, it is shown in the example. I need to run some code in the scope of the delegate when FirstView is popped from the StackView. If you were going to fix my code in a way that did that, how would you fix it?

Comment: @Colin When an element of the StackView is removed, it is eliminated so that what you point out is impossible.

Comment: Just to provide a little more context: In qml, if I define two objects in the same qml file, I can access the top-level properties of either object from the other. For example, in object 2, I can define a function: { console.log(object1.name) }. But I could not access a nested property such as { console.log(object1.child1.name }. If object one had an -attached property-, Attached.name, could I access it in the same way? { console.log(object1.Attached.name) }. And if not, is there a best practice for accessing that property, if needed?

Comment: @eyllanesc -  I can solve my problem (in one way) by adding the following lines to FirstView.qml: signal hiding(); StackView.onDeactivating: { hiding() }, and to the delegate: Connections { target: view; onHiding: { doSomething() }. If you payed attention to my question, you would understand that already. FirstView was not eliminated by the pop() operation (not yet), and this is the purpose of the signal StackView.onDeactivating. Respectfully, if you spent less time trying to 'disprove' people's questions, and more time trying to understand what they were asking, it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no. The Qt documentation partially addresses this: [A Note About Accessing Attached Properties and Signal Handlers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#a-note-about-accessing-attached-properties-and-signal-handlers)

It is not possible to *directly* access the property from a child. Attached properties need to be explicitly read by the class providing them. For your example, the parent class (`StackView`) simply searches for all attached properties it does provide in the child item (`FirstView`) as soon as it gets added, and handles all found properties/signals etc. by connecting them internally to whatever logic provides them.

However, nothing prevents you from gettings the attached property from the parent item, as long as you refer to it by id:

```
sampleProp: view.StackView.someProperty
```

The thing is: This indirect access only works this way for properties and nor for signals, as you can't simply refer to the attached object via `view.StackView` - so sadly, you are stuck with forwarding the signal to the child elements indirectly by creating a second signal in the root item and emitting it when the attached signal gets emitted.

Comment: Okay, yes that's it. The details of scope in qml are quite complex. Thank you.